# How would I compile a Python program to mac that contains multiple files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, compilation

I am trying to compile a sample game I made in pygame to an app that can be run on OSX. I have been trying to do this with py2app, but if there is a different way I would be glad to use that. The main problem I'm having is that my game contains multiple .py files, main.py, settings.py, ship.py, and game_functions.py. All of the documentation and videos I've found online only show how to use py2app to distribute a Python app with a single .py file, not multiple .py files. On top of this I also have a content folder, with an image that is used in my game.

I assume that this has something to do with declaring what modules/packages are being used within the setup.py file, however, I don't know how to do that.

```
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf
```

Above are the imports that are all utilized within my main.py file. The files in this project consist of main.py, settings.py, ship.py, and game_functions.py.

Below is my attempt at a setup.py file.

```
APP = ['main.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Whenever I run the compiled .app, I get an error message saying Main error, with a button for console and terminate.

Comment: @martineau suggested I delete my answer. (Waiting for his feedback)
In case py2app can really not do this you can look at pyinstaller https://www.pyinstaller.org/ which should be doing the job and can handle multiple python files as long as there is one entry point (main python file) that imports the others directly or indirectly

Comment: @gelonida so I don't have to do any separate declarations in anything for the imports? All the extra python files will automatically work in the end app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyinstaller if you have. By going to CMD and entering your File that has the code written in it. Then do "cd C:YourFilePath". After you hit enter you can type in "pyinstaller --onefile YourIdle.py". It then should start compiling.